# Why if $\sup f(x) = \inf g(y)$ then there is $z,w$ such that $f(z) - g(w) < \epsilon.$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$, $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $g: B \subset \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(A), g(B)$ bounded. Why is true that if $\sup f(x) = \inf g(y)$ then there is $z \in A$ and $w \in B$ such that $f(z) - g(w) < \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $v=\sup f(x) = \inf g(y)$ and take $\epsilon >0$

By definition of $\sup f(x)$, it exists $z \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $f(z) > v- \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. And by definition of $\inf g(y)$, it exists $w \in \mathbb R^m$ such that $g(w)<v + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Making the sum of those two inequalities, you get the desired result.

Comment: excellent answer. Thanks a lot!